# when to use which z score equation?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

in some exam past papers I have been doing I have come across the statistics equation

z=(sample mean - mean)/standard deviation

as well as the equation

z = (sample mean - mean)/(standard deviation/sqrt n).

could anyone please explain when to use which equation and what the difference is? thanks so much!

Comment: You need to provide some more information about the context in which these formulations occur. In fact, reading these contexts for yourself might reveal to you the answers to your question. It is not just the _displayed_ equations (possibly with numbering) that are important in your book; it is the context and explanations that precede and follow the displayed equation.

Answer (score 5):

It is the difference between the $z$ score for a datum from an entire population and a sampling.

The $z$ score for a datum $x$ is $z = (x - \mu)/\sigma$ where $\mu$ is the population mean and $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation.

If the datum $x$ is not from the entire population but rather from a sampling from that population then the standard deviation is divided by the square root of the sample size $n$.

Comment: Err... the question is asking about the differences between two formulas in which the _only_ difference is that one formula uses $\sigma$ and the other $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

The $z$-score calculation is designed to answer the question: "How far from typical is this result?"

When dealing with a single datum, the single-value formula $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ gives us the answer.  But when dealing with a whole pile of individual measurements, we expect the Law of Large Numbers, and its more formal cousin the Central Limit Theorem, to take over: more attempts means the mean of our results is going to look more like the population mean.  To model this, we divide the usual standard deviation by $\sqrt{n}$: $z=\frac{\bar x-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$ (mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$).  Then $Z = \dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathrm{Normal}(0,1)$.  This much should be clear.  Now suppose we observe $n$ independent and identically distributed values drawn from $X$; i.e., we consider these $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$.  The distribution of their **sum** is $\mathrm{Normal}(n \mu, \sigma \sqrt{n})$, since $$\mathrm{E}[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n] = \mathrm{E}[X_1] + \mathrm{E}[X_2] + \cdots + \mathrm{E}[X_n]$$ by the linearity of expectation, and $$\mathrm{Var}[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n] \overset{\mathrm{ind}}{=} \mathrm{Var}[X_1] + \mathrm{Var}[X_2] + \cdots + \mathrm{Var}[X_n]$$ when $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent.  So the distribution of the **sample mean** $$\bar x = \frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n) \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$$ because $$\mathrm{E}[cX] = c \mathrm{E}[X]$$ and $$\mathrm{Var}[cX] = c^2 \mathrm{Var}[X]$$ for a scalar constant $c$.  So if we standardize the sample mean, $$Z = \frac{\bar x - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathrm{Normal}(0,1)$$ is the required transformation.  Note that if $n = 1$ in the above formula, we recover the standardization for a single observation, described at the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, Dilip's suggestion should be heeded - without context there is no clear answer to your question. However, in general, the standard deviation in the denominator should match the standard deviation of the variable being normalized. otherwise a Z-score will not be approximated by a standard normal.

I think it is possible, that the two are identical, but with different notation:

$Z=\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma_{\bar X}}=\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma_{X}}$.

Note that the first standard dev. is of the *estimator* while the second is of the *data*.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said by @S2000magician in [this thread](https://www.analystforum.com/t/z-test/83953/13)

- If you're dealing with a single observation (i.e.  next month's return), then you use σ.
- If you're dealing with a mean of observations (i.e. hypothesis test of a sample mean), so σ/√n

When you don't know what to use, ask yourself

> “Is this a confidence interval for a single observation, or for the mean of a bunch of observations?”